# How to rephrase a "primarly opinion based" question?

Tags: discussion

I have seen that questions have been reworded to ask less for opinion and more for facts. However, I don't know how to do this with [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501590/how-to-organize-the-supplied-data-for-a-project).

Is there a good technique to transform an open question into a not primarily opinion based one?

Comment: The thing about "How do I go about this" is that it's really hard to convert your question into one that isn't opinion-based. There's a lot of strategies, and providing a laundry list of them doesn't benefit people, especially on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some "primarily opinion based" questions can be salvaged by removing the parts that are purely asking for opinions and expanding on the parts that aren't. Unfortunately, yours seems to be 100% asking for a recommendation, so it might not be salvagable on Stack Overflow.

There are other sites on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) that might be more suitable though. Take a look at [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/), and [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) to see if you can find what you're looking for. I *do not* recommend simply reposting your question on one of those sites. Look around first to see if questions like yours are welcome by those communities. If they are, you might find existing questions that already answer your question.